# Error with units with deprecated Astropy Blackbody Function

Tags: python, numpy, astropy, astronomy

I received some code and when trying to run it there is a deprecated Blackbody1d function in it. When I try changing the Blackbody1d function to a Blackbody function , it shows

> "UnitConversionError: 'erg / (cm2 Hz s sr)' and 'erg / (cm2 s)' (energy flux/irradiance) are not convertible"

The code is below. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
from astropy.modeling.models import BlackBody1d

wl_bb = np.linspace(100, 1000000, 10000) * u.AA
bb_teff = 3500
bb_scalar = 9.0e-12

bb = BlackBody1d(temperature=teff_known*u.K)
fb = bb(wl_bb)
fb = fb.to(u.erg / u.s / (u.cm * u.cm), equivalencies=u.spectral_density(wl_bb))
```